# Having trouble with PCIe error while booting ,i am using 18.04 version

Tags: 18.04

my system have an error "pcie error" and i m not able to open terminal. my system screen is hold with that error ,no another keys are working ,previous ans i have already read and tried the suggested idea.but still not working .plz help me out.

Comment: Seems like a hardware problem on your PCIe bus. Ubuntu is not designed to run on broken/defective hardware.

Comment: Can you give more detail? I bet there is more information on the screen than literally just "pcie error". Make a photo if it is too much to type.